# UIButton Background image Change programmatically

Tags: ios, ios4, uibutton

How can I change the background image of my UIButton in click event? And refresh it in a few second with the previous image? I mean change it's background image on click and reset it after the click.

Answer (score 14):

```
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourNormalImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageWhenClicking.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

put your clickEvent image as highlighted image of your button..

Comment: my background image is changing with the following code : [cell.ansBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; but i want this change in two button.then i want to reset the button with previous image.....

Comment: If you want this change this to second button too put the same code there [yourSecondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourNormalImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourSecondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageWhenClicking.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Answer (score 6):

The above answer is not working because it doesn't change the background but the side image of the `UIButton`, to change the background image use:

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```